# Save UDP stream to mp4 in different bitrate or videosize using Gstreamer

Tags: udp, gstreamer, mp4, h.264, rtp

I am trying to store UDP stream to different size MP4 files.

Used 1080 video to generate UDP stream for development purpose later it will be replaced by IP Camera

UDP Server sink :

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin    ! ffmpegcolorspace     ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=1920,height=1088 ! timeoverlay halignment=right ! clockoverlay time-format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"  ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=2998 speed-preset=superfast     ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96     ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

With following pipeline i can play UDP stream with same video display size at which UDP is streaming

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 \
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01ADdoFB+/8CqwIAEAAAAMAQAAADKPFCqg\\=\\,aO88gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1045780718, clock-base=(uint)2990047309, seqnum-base=(uint)65496" \
! rtph264depay \
! avdec_h264 \
! autovideosink
```

Now, I want to save this stream in different video screen size MP4 file.

I am trying following pipe line, but it gives error

```
erroneous pipeline: could not link videoscale0 to h264parse0

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 \
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01ADdoFB+/8CqwIAEAAAAMAQAAADKPFCqg\\=\\,aO88gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1045780718, clock-base=(uint)2990047309, seqnum-base=(uint)65496" \
! rtph264depay \
! decodebin \
! queue \
! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! h264parse ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=2998 speed-preset=superfast ! queue \
! autovideosink
```

Use autovideosink for development later it will be replaced by filesink

[Edited] 30th Dec, 2015

I made some changes in pipeline and it is now working but not consistent. It works sometimes and fail sometimes. I think, it is synchronization issues in RTP stream and decoder However current changes are ,

1. change decodebin to avdec_h264, why ? 
   I saw GStreamer pipeline graph, decodebin's src was not connect
   to videoconvert's sink. so pipeline was actually broken.
   Replace decodebin with avdec_h264 and pipeline is complete.

Current pipeline :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01ADdoFB+/8CqwIAEAAAAMAQAAADKPFCqg\\=\\,aO88gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1045780718, clock-base=(uint)2990047309, seqnum-base=(uint)65496" ! rtpjitterbuffer  ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=2998 speed-preset=superfast ! queue ! filesink location=video-2.mp4
```

But now getting below errors,

```
0:00:00.217021017 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.217066624 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.217085496 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.217101775 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.217118391 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.217133568 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.217231425 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 1
0:00:00.217260466 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: error while decoding MB 0 1, bytestream 1286
0:00:00.242377091 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.242642392 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.242670418 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.242689807 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.242709715 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: first_mb_in_slice overflow
0:00:00.242728336 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.242821704 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 1
0:00:00.242851186 18449      0x1c50850 ERROR                  libav :0:: error while decoding MB 0 1, bytestream 1193
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one linked for me.
decodebin already provides you video/x-raw.

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01ADdoFB+/8CqwIAEAAAAMAQAAADKPFCqg\\=\\,aO88gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1045780718, clock-base=(uint)2990047309, seqnum-base=(uint)65496" \
! rtph264depay \
! decodebin ! queue \
! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=2998 speed-preset=superfast \
! queue ! autovideosink
```